# Outer crossvalidation cycle in caret package (R)?

Tags: r, cross-validation, prediction, caret

Could somebody provide a nice example code how to best implement an outer crossvalidation cycle using the caret package in R? The package provides a convenient trainControl() argument to ajust the inner crossvalidation. However I would like to embed this into multiple outer crossvalidation cycles to get a more stable estimate of the prediction performance of the estimated models!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Inner and outer CV are used to perform classifier selection not to get a better prediction on the estimate. To get a better estimate, do a repeated cv. So to perform a 10-repeates 5-fold CV use

```
trainControl(method = "repeatedcv",number = 5,
             ## repeated ten times
             repeats = 10)
```

But if what you really want is a nested CV, for example to select between a random forest or a svm) then as far as  know you have to do the outer CV explicitly. What I did for an outer 5-fold, inner 10-fold was:

```
ntrain=length(ytrain)    
train.ext=createFolds(ytrain,k=5,returnTrain=TRUE)
test.ext=lapply(train.ext,function(x) (1:ntrain)[-x])

for (i in 1:5){
    model<-train(Class ~ ., data = training[train.ext[[i]]],
                 trControl=trainControl(method = "cv",number = 10),
                 ...
    ...
    }
```

Comment: I've never really seen a case where nested CV is worth the effort but I did put in the [caret development list](https://github.com/topepo/caret/issues/70) a few weeks ago. It may take a while.

Comment: This is caret author's blog on nested cv: http://appliedpredictivemodeling.com/blog/2017/9/2/njdc83d01pzysvvlgik02t5qnaljnd

Comment: @Jacques Wainer your statement that repeated cv is preferred to nested cv for getting a better estimate is very interesting - do you have any citation for that? does it refer to robustness, and how is this better addressed in repeated cv than nested cv?